# VSCode intellisense working with a node project and custom require function

Tags: node.js, intellisense, visual-studio-code

I am joining a nodejs project that is already pretty far along. They have defined global helper methods to some of their most widely used folders to shorthand requires from anywhere. E.g.:

```
utility('') = require(${rootFolder}/lib/utility).
```

I have tested replacing an import with a standard require and the intellisense works perfectly; however, I can't demand that we change every file because of my choice to use VS Code instead of webstorm.

Is there any way I can configure VS Code to recognize those custom requires for intellisense on those imports?